# How did this character defeat Usagi so readily?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

In the third episode of the second season of *Alice in Borderland*,

> Niragi

gets in a hand-to-hand fight with Usagi, where he quickly gains the advantage over her and is able to knock her unconscious without much trouble.

On the one hand, Usagi, though smaller, has shown strength and athleticism that is basically Olympic level, as seen in the same episode where she jumps across what has to be a twenty-foot gap with a short running start and manages to hang on with a single arm upon landing on the other side without suffering any apparent injuries. On the other hand, Niragi, by all appearances, hasn't really shown substantial physical *strength* (weapons skills and lack of concern for his safety, perhaps) and is quite weak at this point, to the extent that he is constantly coughing up blood and and has difficulty walking, not to mention limited depth perception due to his bandaged eye. Indeed, Arisu himself, hardly an athlete, manages to beat him up without much trouble at all shortly thereafter. The fight should *seemingly* be very one-sided in favor of Usagi, but instead it goes the other way around.

How, then, was Niragi able to get the upper hand so easily? Is he simply much stronger than he seems? Was Usagi not putting up as much of a fight for some reason (e.g., due to the suicidal impulses that she demonstrated earlier in the season)? Or is there something else at play?

Answer (score 2):

Usagi is undeniably strong and physically capable but at no point in the program is she shown as an experienced fighter.

During her first face off with Niragi in Series 1 her tactics are basically limited to jumping on his back to restrain him and biting him when he tries to molest her. Neither action results in any long term success and when she tries the same thing on Aguni she is repeatedly and easily flung aside (understandably as Aguni is basically a human tank who can survive multiple gunshot wounds).

Admittedly Niragi is in a weaker state by this point but it doesn't seem to slow him down too much throughout the second series.

Comment: Plausible, but at that point Niragi was not basically dying. He was extremely weakened by the latter point, as evidenced by his trouble walking, chronic internal bleeding, and the fact that Arisu was able to beat him up with little issue.

Comment: Indeed, he was injured to the extent that never got the better of anyone else in a physical fight in Season 2—he was able to touch the base by spitting blood in someone's eyes and threaten people with guns, but that was about all. He didn't even land a single hit on Arisu. I don't want to call "plot contrivance," but it does seem as if it was mainly there so that Arisu would have to do the last part alone, and possibly to move their relationship along or something.

Comment: Very much accepted - out of universe the second attempted rape was clearly a narrative device to move the story along. I think though that there was sufficient lampshade hanging before to make it not completely implausible in universe.

Comment: True. I think it is particularly egregious, though, when compared to the fight with the Queen of Spades. The latter is uninjured and in peak physical condition, which is why she became the Queen of Spades in the first place. She gets the better of Usagi, but it takes her some time and Usagi is still conscious afterward and quickly recovers. Niragi is recovering from what look like third-degree burns, has one eye bandaged, is notably slowed by a leg injury, and looks as if he is within days of dying from internal bleeding, and he gets the better of her much more quickly and decisively.